# Generic attribute access in C++

Tags: c++, simplify, boilerplate

I am using this wrapper function many time. Is there a way to write a generic template from it?

```
void setFoo(const Napi::CallbackInfo &info)
{
    if (info.Length() < 1 || !info[0].IsNumber()) {
        Napi::TypeError::New(info.Env(), "arg1::Number expected").ThrowAsJavaScriptException();
    }

    object->foo= info[0].As<Napi::Number>().DoubleValue();
}
```

For instance, I would like to have:

```
setFoo (that sets the value of object->foo)
setBar (that sets the value of object->bar)
setFoobar (that sets the value of object->foobar)
setWhatever...
```

Is this something feasible in C++?

Comment: I presume that `Napi::TypeError::New` throws an exception (otherwise the shown code will obviously be buggy). If so, then have you simply considered writing a function called, say, "get_number()" that contains everything shown above, except that it `return info[0].As<Napi::Number>().DoubleValue();` instead, and then it's simply `object->foo=get_number();`, `object->bar=get_number();`, and so on. Why overcomplicate things? "The more you overthink the plumbing, the easier it is to stop the drain", Scotty, Star Trek III.

Comment: [Pointers to members](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/pointer#Pointers_to_members)?